# hash_map implementation (Solaris 10, g++ 2.95.3) with default_alloc

Tags: c++, memory-management, hashmap, coredump, solaris-10

I am getting a core dump, the `pstack core` shows as below:

```
 fed4ebd4 _lwp_kill (b, fe984948, 0, 1, fffffffc, 0) + 8
 fdbd6c6c skgesigOSCrash (ffbfb5d4, ffbfb47c, fec31460, feb7536c, bc0f4, bc000) + 4c
 fe1253a0 kpeDbgSignalHandler (ffbfb5d4, b13d630, 9e800, b, ffbfb9dd, 6060000) + 2f0
 fdbd71ac skgesig_sigactionHandler (b, ffbfc260, febef8f8, 0, fec314a0, ffbfb5c0) + f0
 fed4b00c __sighndlr (b, ffbfc260, ffbfbfa8, fdbd70bc, 0, 1) + c
 fed3f6bc call_user_handler (b, 0, 8, 0, fc7f2a00, ffbfbfa8) + 3b8
 fed3f8a4 sigacthandler (b, ffbfc260, ffbfbfa8, 29a8d0, 0, 0) + 60
 --- called from signal handler with signal 11 (SIGSEGV) ---
 fecd8028 _malloc_unlocked (308, bad8f38, bad8f38, bad8f38, fffffffc, 0) + 22c
 fecd7de0 malloc   (304, 1, ea654, 297f1c, fedc23f0, fedcc5e0) + 4c
 002f0ee8 malloc   (304, ffbfddd4, ba56c40, 1c, 3a, ba56d7d) + 54
 001c4c78 allocate__t23__malloc_alloc_template1i0Ui (304, 0, 0, ffbfd99f, 0, 80808080)
+ c
 001c4cfc allocate__t24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (304, 304, ffbfd99f, 1, b, 0) +
18
 0029a80c allocate__t12simple_alloc2ZPt15_Hashtable_node1Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt
18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiZt24
__default_alloc_template2b0i0Ui (c1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ffffffff) + 20
 00299d38 _M_allocate__t18_Vector_alloc_base3ZPt15_Hashtable_node1Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_st
ring3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocat
or1ZiZt9allocator1Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1Zib1Ui (ffbfddf4, c1, 0, ffffffff, a, 808080
80) + 10
 0029a8d0 _M_allocate_and_copy__H1ZPPt15_Hashtable_node1Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt1
8string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1Zi_t6ve
ctor2ZPt15_Hashtable_node1Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt (ffbf
ddf4, c1, 0, 0, ffbfe047, 1) + 1c
 00299e24 reserve__t6vector2ZPt15_Hashtable_node1Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string
_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiZt9allocator
1Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiUi (ffbfddf4, c1, ffbfdb74, 0, ffbfe047, 7ffffff0) + 48
 00297f1c _M_copy_from__t9hashtable6Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1
ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiZt12basic_string3ZcZt18st
ring_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z7strhashZt10_Select1st1Zt4pa (ffbf
ddf0, ffbfddd4, c1, ffbfdbe8, 38, ba56602) + 3c
 0029ace8 __t9hashtable6Zt4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__defa
ult_alloc_template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiZt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_tr
aits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_template2b0i0Z7strhashZt10_Select1st1Zt4pair2ZCt12basi (ffbf
ddf0, ffbfddd4, ba56c40, 1c, 3a, ba56d7d) + 124
 002998ac __t8hash_map5Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_
template2b0i0Zt6vector2ZiZt9allocator1ZiZ7strhashZ5streqZt9allocator1Zt6vector2ZiZt9all
ocator1ZiRCt8hash_map5Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_a (ffbf
ddf0, ffbfddd4, ffbfdcef, ffbfdcee, ffbfdce0, 80808080) + 14
 00294754 __Q212Notification4._47RCQ212Notification4._47 (ffbfddec, ffbfddd0, 484564, 1
, b, 0) + 1c
 0029adf8 __t4pair2ZCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_tem
plate2b0i0ZQ212Notification9_RecordIdRCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24_
_default_alloc_template2b0i0RCQ212Notification9_RecordId (ffbfdde8, ffbfde88, ffbfddd0,
 0, 0, ffffffff) + 2c
 00299fcc __vc__t8hash_map5Zt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_al
loc_template2b0i0ZQ212Notification9_RecordIdZ7strhashZ5streqZt9allocator1ZQ212Notificat
ion9_RecordIdRCt12basic_string3ZcZt18string_char_traits1ZcZt24__default_alloc_tem (4845
64, ffbfde88, ffbfde80, ffffffff, a, 80808080) + 2c
 002948a8 _Add__12NotificationPCcP8RecordId (484560, ba56d60, 0, ffbfe047, ffbfe047, 1)
 + a0
...
```

The core dump is coming when using hash_map with Solaris 10, g++ 2.95.3 compiled. 
What's __Q212Notification4._47RCQ212Notification4._47?
Please suggest if any clue.

Comment: That's an old compiler. Can you switch to something more recent? The name looks like some sort of copy constructor, but I can't fully demangle it (the name still contains the _47s).

Comment: `SIGSEGV` in `malloc()`?  The heap is almost certainly corrupted.